# How to prove this integral function is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Given $$G(z) = \int_{1+i}^{z}\text{sin} (\theta^2) d\theta$$

Prove that $G(z)$ is an analytic function of $z$.

I read that integration preserves analyticity. But why is that true when $z$ is in the integral bounds?
What if the function is something different instead of $\text{sin}(\theta^2)$, say $f(z)$ which is only analytic in a certain region $R$ and I integrate along a path that goes outside $R$?

Comment: It won't make any difference, but do you mean $\sin(\theta^2)$?  Or do you mean $(\sin\theta)^2$, usually written as $\sin^2\theta\,$?

Comment: I edited the question, taking for granted it was meant $\text{sin}^2\theta$ and not $\text{sin}(\theta^2)$. In case the latter is true and my edits get accepted, please edit the LaTeX so that it displays the integrand properly.

Comment: I mean $sin(\theta^2)$. I have updated the post. Also, do you mean that as long as the integrand function is analytic for some region, $G(\mathbb{z})$ will be analytic everywhere?

Comment: Regularity in some set $U$ won't impact regularity in a set $V$ that's "too far" from $\overline{U}$, even if you ask for continuity on $U \cup V$.

Comment: The analyticity of $G$ is part of the proof of Morera's theorem by the way: [Morera's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194414)

Comment: @BrunoB that's what I needed. Very clean proof. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking about one of the standard theorems in complex analysis.

> Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb C$ be [holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) function on open star-domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb C$. Let $p\in \Omega$ be point such that for any $z \in \Omega$, the line segment $<p, z>$ is contained in $\Omega$. Then function $F(z) = \int_{<p, z>} f(\theta)\operatorname d \! \theta$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and $F' = f$.

This theorem is step in proving [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem). For proof see Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* chapter 10: proof of 10.14 (what you are interested in), and statements of 10.6 and 10.16 (holomorphic functions are exactly the ones representable by power series).

Answer (score 3):

> If $f(z)$ is analytic on simply connected subset $D$ of complex plane $\mathbb C$ and $\gamma$ is any arbitrary curve  inside $D$, then the function $F(z)=\int_\gamma f(t)dt$ is also analytic.

In your case $f(z)=\sin (z^2)$ is entire i.e. analytic on whole $\mathbb C$, so the antiderivative is also analytic regardless of the choice of  $\gamma$.